# ¿Qué significa en Colombia la frase "Relaje el pony"?

Tags: modismos, colombia

Hace un par de años escuché a una colombiana decir *"relaje el pony"*. ¿Qué quiso decir con esto?

Comment: Necesitaríamos más contexto. Además, ¿cuál es tu suposición? ¿Investigaste algo que pieda ser relevante? Dale a [edit] para añadir estas importantes consideraciones... y por supuesto bienvenido/a a [spanish.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### *Relaje el Pony:*
>
> Forma de decirle a un amigo, que debe calmarse y encontrar su paz interior.
>
> - [Diccionario Colombiano de la calle](https://steemit.com/babel/@yenipaola/diccionario-colombiano-de-la-calle-2-parte)

Answer (score 1):

calma, relajese parcero que no pasa nada. Cuando se le dice a alguien. RELAJE EL PONY, Singinifica que no se preocupe.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. **Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser significativamente distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido** (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a la respuesta aceptada. Dale al [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.